Airflow Kubernetes Executor - Tasks waiting in scheduled state
I have a microk8s cluster setup with the offical airflow helm chart. The cluster size is 32 nodes with each node having 16 cores and 32GB memory each.
The following values were changed in the values.yaml file to allow more tasks to run concurrently:
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_TASKS_PER_DAG
    value: '384'
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_POOL_TASK_SLOT_COUNT
    value: '384'
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM
    value: '384'

The problem I have is that many tasks are scheduled and wait until other tasks are completed before they are queued and start running.
This happens even though the nodes are only using ~25% of their CPU and memory.
Is there another setting that I have to alter?
